# When we instantiate in string in java using new operator where is 3rd object created

Tags: java, string

In Java `String S=new String(" ");` will create 3 different objects, 1 in string pool area and 1 more in non string pool area, can any 1 tell me how and where is the 3rd object created

Comment: *"...will create 3 different objects..."* Where did you get that information?

Answer (score 4):

> In Java String S=new String(" "); will create 3 different objects

No it won't. It only creates the two you were talking about (and only one new one if the string " " is already in the intern pool).